# Solve $\frac {dy}{dx} -\frac xy + x^3 \cos y =0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the general solution of the following differential equation

$$\frac {dy}{dx} -\frac xy + x^3 \cos y =0.$$

My failed attempts include:

a. Substitution of  $v = y/x$

b. Multiplying by dx and fit the equation to be solvable using by inspection

c. Transformation of ODE into Linear

d. Setting $\frac{dx}{dy}$ and solve with $ y$ as independent

The $\cos(y)$ term makes it impossible to proceed.

Comment: What is the exact context, is this an exercise, if yes, what kind of solution is demanded? If it is the result of some model, could you give some context that shows that the DE is correctly derived?